# Html keep keyboard visible on iphone through jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios5, jquery-mobile

I want to keep the keyboard visible on iphone whenever focus is moved from one input field to another programmatically.
The code works fine when I set focus for the first time but fails to do so subsequently.

Here is a snippet of code. Any idea how to keep the keyboard visible?
live demo http://navtest.0fees.net/del/, open it on iphone or ipad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
body{background-color: #efefef;}
input:focus{ color:red; font-size:30px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); }
.button {
  font-family: Arial; color: #ffffff; font-size: 35px; padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 28px; -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666; border: solid #005157 2px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#c3f7f4), to(#095461));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3f7f4, #095461);
}
.button:hover { background: #19ad02; }
</style>
    <head>
        <title>I Pad</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" name="" id="name" value="" class="button">Submit</button>
        <input type="text" id="kb" value="" class="button"/>
        <input type="text" id="kb1" value="" class="button"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#name').click(function(){            
                    $('#kb').focus();
                    $('#kb').blur(); //not important
                    $('#kb1').focus();
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I want to display keyboard on iphone whenever focus is set to an input field" Isn't that just the default browser behavior on the iPhone?

Comment: yeah it is but please read the full post. keyboard hides when i move focus to another input box programmatically.

Comment: Gotcha; it was a little confusing because it sounded like you were trying to replicate default behavior with code.  You might want to re-word your question to make it clearer that you are trying to use code to solve the problematic browser behavior (and not trying to use code to show the keyboard in the first place).

Comment: I've replicated the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvc63/1/ Visit http://jsfiddle.net/Jvc63/ to see it work

Comment: sorry.. that does not work try opening http://jsfiddle.net/Jvc63/1 in ipad or iphone. the keyboard hides as soon focus is moved to second text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think iPhone has been designed in such a way to trigger keyboard only through some user action. That is why through manual click on the button it is possible to moved the focus to input box and open keyboard, but any other attempt to programmatically click a button and from button's event handler set focus to input box to open keyboard won't work.

I guess the only option I am left with is to set attribute of all my input boxes to readonly and on clicking it open a transparent input box just on top of it. Then take the value from the transparent input box and set it whichever readonly input box I want.

And subsequently keep changing the position of transparent input box to whichever readonly input box I am setting value for.

If anyone has a better idea of doing it, I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

*** EDIT #2 ***

*It looks like there is no solution to this question (so far at least).*

*** END EDIT #2 ***

I think when you "blur" a field in Safari it hides the keyboard, and then when you "focus" a new field it shows the keyboard.  So, unless you're doing something strange (like manually blurring the old field after focusing the new one) I honestly don't understand why you'd have the behavior you describe.

*** EDIT ***

*Just looked at your code and realized that the last thing you do is a focus, which should bring the keyboard back up.  However, you are doing a manual blur; I'd try removing that first and see if it fixes things.*

*** END EDIT ***

One possible solution to solve it though is to use `e.preventDefault()` from inside a `onBlur` event handler.  This should prevent the browser-default behavior of hiding the keyboard.

Comment: This code replicated behavior that I need in some other application where i constantly need to move my focus to other input boxes programmatically, so I cant remove the first focus. I tried your other solution, from what I understood you suggested something like this $('#kb').onblur(e.preventDefault()), but even this is not working.

Comment: "so I cant remove the first focus" - it's not the first focus that (I think) is the problem, it's the blur.  As for trying my second idea, you were close; try `$('#kb').blur(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})`.

Comment: I don't need the blur command, initially i didn't have it, but just to try out I put it there. I tried your second idea but its still the same with and without blur.

Comment: Shoot.  Another idea: try calling `click` after the `focus`, so `$('#kb1').focus().click();`

Comment: I tried it earlier also, but its no good. :( I even tried to put some delay between the first blur and second focus but still the keyboard hides.

Comment: This sounds silly, but what about doing `$('#kb1').focus().blur().focus()`

Comment: Wow, go Steve Jobs.  Ok my last idea is that you try calling it from a timeout, ie. instead of: `$('#kb1').focus()` do `window.setTimeout(function() {$('#kb1').focus()}, 100})`

Comment: I already have tried it, saw it on stack overflow as answer to some other related question.. but its no success..

Comment: Wow, I'm out of ideas.  I'll leave this answer as a list of "things that don't work", but hopefully someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: NP, I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.